# Moving a file from ROOT directory resulted in loss of data

Tags: linux, mv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before moving, I checked the directory and it had all the contents in it.
Then I moved it to a directory in my C drive (I'm using WSL) with this command:
`sudo mv c_dir/ mnt/c/Users/L570/Documents/to_be_compiled/`

When I `cd`ed my way into `to_be_compiled`, it certainly was there. But it was empty.

I found this command:
`chown erebus /mnt/c/Users/L570/Documents/to_be_compiled/c_dir/`
on another question, but that didn't change anything either.

I tried `ls -a`, but there really are no files inside.

Question: Have I lost all the files, or is it about permissions?

Comment: The question and the prose are at odds.  Did you _copy_ or _move_ the file?  Was it a file or directory?

Comment: @DopeGhoti remedied it. It was a ```directory```. I ```moved``` it.

Comment: as long as you are in the `/` root folder when you ran that command, then that looks like a valid move ... at least in WSL2

Comment: No one knows what happened.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your `history` show  any other commands around that time that might help indicate the problem?

Comment: No, there aren't any such commands. There were also no warnings or errors emitted during moving the directory either. I'm not very familiar with file permissions but I'll read up on them. Hopefully I'm missing one and the data is recoverable.

Comment: Do the files inside this folder have really long names? Maybe it has to do with the file name length limit on linux/windows being different.

Comment: They were mainly ```c``` source files. I believe one or two may be 20 characters at most, but not more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say from the comments that we're all confused on exactly what happened in this case based on the current information.  If it helps, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue using the following scenario in Ubuntu on WSL:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir c_dir
cd c_dir
sudo touch abc 1 2 3
cd /
sudo mv c_dir/ mnt/c/Users/ntd/Documents/to_be_compiled
```

The directory `/c_dir` was renamed (moved) to the `to_be_compiled` directory in the proper location, with all files present.

That said, best practice would certainly be to use the fully qualified directory names (starting with a `/`) rather than the relative form that you used.  I'm wondering if perhaps the files are someplace else based on your working directory when you ran the `mv` command.

Note that the actual ownership and permissions *will* vary depending on whether you have changed the automount settings in `/etc/wsl.conf`.

With a default WSL installation, the files will be owned by your *user* once they are moved to the Windows drive, with 777 permissions.

I have mine changed slightly, with the following in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

With that in place, WSL attempts to mimic the actual Linux ownership and permissions, so the files are owned by `root` (since they were moved with `sudo`) and the permissions are 644.

Comment: The file permissions are 500 right now. Interestingly, I was not able to reproduce the same problem when I experimented with it. But what I forgot to mention was that, the file originally resided in a folder on the C disk, which I accidentally moved to the root directory. I can still see the files in Windows File Explorer's *"Frequent Folders"*, but upon opening them, I see a prompt saying *"Location is not available."*

Comment: @Haris Hmm - When you accidentally moved them, what were you using?  Windows File Explorer?  Using the `\\wsl.localhost\<distro_name>` or `\\wsl$\<distro_name>` path?  That *shouldn't* have been possible, since WSL should treat Windows application as running as your *WSL user*, not root.  Since your regular user shouldn't have access to `/` in Linux, *that* move should have been denied.  Is there any chance that the files were actually moved to a different location?  Perhaps somewhere under your `/home/<username>` folder in WSL?

Comment: @Haris If you know the name of one of the missing files, try running `sudo find / -xdev -name "filename"` and see if you can find the missing files elsewhere.  That will include every location in WSL, but *not* on the Windows drive.

Comment: Update: Running that command in WSL failed. But running a similar command in ```windows cmd``` succeeded. It seems that the command created a directory ```c_dir``` in ```C:\c_dir\```. Thank you.